# What's "Converted Portable Device Control device" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, device-manager

After plugging out my USB keyboard and my USB mouse receiver from my Windows 10 laptop, I'm left with these two keyboards in Device Manager:

[image: Keyboards in Device Manager]

The *Standard PS/2 Keyboard* is the internal laptop keyboard, but what's the *HID Keyboard Device*?

Windows 10 says:

[image]

> Location: on Converted Portable Device Control device

**What's this?** Where does this keyboard come from?

---

Edit: devices by connection view:

[image: Device Manager - devices by connection view]

Comment: It could be a virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the name of parent device of this HID keyboard. To see it, open “devices by connection” or “devices by container” view. 
If the  parent device is USB, the name comes from its firmware (descriptors).

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with the "devices by connection" view, but I still can't figure out where this device comes from?

Comment: From brief googling, this is something specific to HP or Dell laptops. Laptop vendors are known for installing strange virtual HID devices. The "consumer control device" is HID collection that contains function keys such as volume control. The "system controller" is HID collection for sleep and power keys. But why they need a keyboard, that's,  produce normal keys?  Not clear why exactly.

Comment: Thank you, that's a Dell indeed, this is probably the explanation.